# Multiple Conditions with subquery (SWITCH or IIF)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have hit a wall in a query that will return the Vehicle ID number with the most recent sale date if the vehicle has been sold, sale cancelled, and re-soled (this is accomplished by checking if there are an odd number of transactions associated with a vehicle)

Sometimes the most recent transaction date will not be the Final sale but rather the cancel transaction (the system batches / processes transactions in a unintuitive order).

Note: I'm using MS Acces

**What I need help with**

Write a Query to determine IF the most recent transaction returned is the cancel transaction, THEN return the second most recent transaction.

### SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT N.vin, 
                N.[trans category], 
                N.[model category], 
                Max(N.[trans date]) 
FROM   new_bbss N 
WHERE  N.[trans category] NOT LIKE '*Individual*' 
       AND ( N.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Corporate*' 
       AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Partners*' 
       AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Special*' 
       AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Employee*' 
       AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Mobile*' 
       AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*JLR FLEET*' 
       AND N.vin IN(SELECT vin 
                    FROM   new_bbss 
                    WHERE  [retailer code] LIKE 'R*' 
                           AND new_bbss.vin NOT IN(SELECT vin 
                                                   FROM   cleansed_vins) 
                    GROUP  BY vin 
                    HAVING Count(vin) > 1 
                           AND Count(vin) MOD 2 = 1) 
GROUP  BY N.vin, 
          N.[trans category], 
          N.[model category]
```

### Data Structure

[image: DataStructure]

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a few sample data

Comment: add "AND [CancelField] <> true" (or to that effect) to the end of your where clause?

Comment: @PaulFrancis Please see attached edit

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not eliminate "cancel" transaction with a subquery.  See the 5th line of the code below.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT N.vin, 
            N.[trans category], 
            N.[model category], 
            Max(N.[trans date]) 
FROM   (Select * from new_bbss where new_bbss.[trans category] NOT LIKE '*Cancel*')  N 
WHERE  N.[trans category] NOT LIKE '*Individual*' 
   AND ( N.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Corporate*' 
   AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Partners*' 
   AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Special*' 
   AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Employee*' 
   AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*Mobile*' 
   AND ( n.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE '*JLR FLEET*' 
   AND N.vin IN(SELECT vin 
                FROM   new_bbss 
                WHERE  [retailer code] LIKE 'R*' 
                       AND new_bbss.vin NOT IN(SELECT vin 
                                               FROM   cleansed_vins) 
                GROUP  BY vin 
                HAVING Count(vin) > 1 
                       AND Count(vin) MOD 2 = 1) 
GROUP  BY N.vin, 
      N.[trans category], 
      N.[model category]
```